# What is the real memory available in Docker container?

Tags: docker, memory-limit

I've run mongodb service via docker-compose like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    mem_limit: 4GB
```

If I run docker stats I can see 4 GB allocated:

```
CONTAINER ID   NAME                     CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O    PIDS
cf3ccbd17464   michal_mongo_1           0.64%     165.2MiB / 4GiB       4.03%     10.9kB / 4.35kB   0B / 483kB   35
```

But I run this command I get RAM from my laptop which is 32 GB:

```
~$ docker exec michal_mongo_1 free -g
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:             31           4          17           0           9          24
Swap:             1           0           1
```

How does mem_limit affect the memory size then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`free` (and other utilities like `top`) will not report correct numbers inside a memory-constraint container because it gathers its information from `/proc/meminfo` which is not namespaced.

If you want the actual limit, you must use the entries populated by `cgroup` pseudo-filesystem under `/sys/fs/cgroup`.

For example:

```sh
docker run --rm -i --memory=128m busybox cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes
```

The real-time usage information is available under `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.stat`.

You will probably need the resident-set-size (`rss`), for example (inside the container):

```
grep -E -e '^rss\s+' /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.stat
```

For a more in-depth explanation, see also [this article](https://ops.tips/blog/why-top-inside-container-wrong-memory/)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I assume it means a process inside Docker container sees 4 GB in this case, not 32 GB.

Comment: @MichalŠpondr, yes it sees the real limit as imposed by `cgroups`. Also `memory.stat` will provide more detailed information on real-time usage